# c execvp grep environment variables, when grep does not find anything

Tags: c, linux, bash

I'm trying to build a small c program that study environment variables.
When I run the program with a parameter it should mimic

> printenv | grep parameterlist | sort | less

So I use pipes to connect all these outputs but now the problem is when i input a environment variable that does not exist the program still runs through everything and ideally i want it to exit after the grep.

Here is the code where i execute grep with execvp and perror but perror is only when execvp dosen't work.

I know from the man pages that grep gives 0 when one or more lines selected and 1 when No lines where selected and >1 when an error occurred. How do i handle when grep selects no lines and exit the program without continuing though sort and less?

```
    execvp( "grep", argv);  /* runs grep */
    perror( "Cannot exec grep" ); exit( 1 );




/* CHILD that handles grep function.
This child executes grep.

*/
if(pid == 0) 
{   
    if(-1 == dup2(pipa[READ],STDIN_FILENO)) /* redirect pipe1 to stdin */
    {perror("Cannot dup"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}

    if(-1 == dup2(pipa2[WRITE],STDOUT_FILENO)) /* redirect stdout to pipe2 */
    {perror("Cannot dup"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}

    if(-1 == close(pipa[WRITE])) /* Close write, we dont need it */
    {perror("Cannot close pipe (write-end)[GREP]"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}

    if(-1 == close(pipa[READ])) /* Close read on pipe1 */
    {perror("Cannot close pipe (read-end)[GREP]"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}

    if(-1 == close(pipa2[READ])) /* Close read on pipe2, we dont need it */
    {perror("Cannot close pipe2 (read-end)[GREP]"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}

    if(-1 == close(pipa2[WRITE])) /* Close write on pipe2, we we have it on stdout now */
    {perror("Cannot close pipe2 (read-end)[GREP]"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}

    if(argc > 1) /* filter or no */
    {
        argv[0] = "grep";
        printf("%s",argv[0]);

        execvp( "grep", argv);  /* runs grep */
        perror( "Cannot exec grep" ); exit( 1 );
    }
    exit(0);
}

/* PARENT */
if(argc < 2) /* No arguments? */
{
    if(-1 == dup2(pipa2[WRITE],pipa[WRITE])) /* Redirect stdin to pipe2 write (which is in STDOUT_FILENO) */
    {perror("Cannot dup"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}
}


/* Sends enivomrent data to grep */
for(i=0; envp[i] != 0; i++)
{
    write(pipa[WRITE],envp[i],strlen(envp[i]));
    write(pipa[WRITE],"\n",1);
}

nchildren++;

/* Create 3rd pipe */
if(pipe(pipa3) == -1)
{exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}

/* Close 1st pipe */
if(-1 == close(pipa[WRITE]))
{perror("Cannot close pipe (write-end)"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}
if(-1 == close(pipa[READ]))
{perror("Cannot close pipe (read-end)"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}
/* Close write from second pipe */
if(-1 == close(pipa2[WRITE]))
{perror("Cannot close pipe (read-end)"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}


/* fork again */
if((pid = fork()) == -1) /* ERROR */
{exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}

/* CHILD that handles sort function.
This child executes sort.

*/
if(pid == 0) 
{   
    if(-1 == dup2(pipa2[READ],STDIN_FILENO)) /* redirect pipe2 read to stdin */
    {perror("Cannot dup"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}

    if(-1 == dup2(pipa3[WRITE],STDOUT_FILENO)) /* redirect stdout to pipe3 write */
    {perror("Cannot dup"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}

    if(-1 == close(pipa2[READ])) /* Close write, we have it on stdin now */
    {perror("Cannot close pipe (write-end)[SORT]"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}

    if(-1 == close(pipa3[READ])) /* Close read on pipe3, we dont need it */
    {perror("Cannot close pipe (write-end)[SORT]"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}

    if(-1 == close(pipa3[WRITE])) /* Close write on pipe3, we have it on stdout now*/
    {perror("Cannot close pipe (write-end)[SORT]"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}

    (void) execlp( "sort", "", NULL );  /* runs sort */
    perror( "Cannot exec sort" ); exit( 1 );
}

/* PARENT */
if(-1 == close(pipa2[READ])) /* Close read from pipe2 */
{perror("Cannot close pipe (read-end)[PARENT]"); exit(1);}
if(-1 == close(pipa3[WRITE])) /* Close write from pipe3*/
{perror("Cannot close pipe (write-end)[PARENT]"); exit(1);}
```

Comment: You have to post the rest of the code too. It's not easy to help with just this information.

Comment: The return code of `grep` (or any program run via `exec*()`) will be available to the parent process of the process that called `exec*()` via a call to `wait*()`.

Answer (score 1):

If execvp fails, _exit will be called.

execvp's man page:

Return Value
If any of the exec() family functions returns, an error will have occurred. The return value is -1, and the global variable errno will be set to indicate the error.